# Overleaf Error in figure: illegal parameter number in definition of /reserved@a

Tags: citing, overleaf

I am having trouble fixing the following issue:

> illegal parameter number in definition of /reserved@a argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }. runaway argument?

This error shows up within a figure enviroment:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{excel1.PNG}
        \caption{Liste der zehn Themengebiete \protected\cite{codebook}}
        \label{fig:code}
    \end{figure}
    \FloatBarrier
```

To me, there does not seem to be an extra bracket. I do know that LaTeX addresses internal expressions with @ but i do not know how to solve it. The document can produce a pdf and the figure is shown but the reference is missing and the figure does not appear in the list of figures.
When compiled the error log of Overleaf shows this:

```
{\numberline {4}{\ignorespaces Liste der zehn Themengebiete \protected \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \contentsline was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.5 ...f ({(}\def ){)}\let \reserved@d =<\def \par
                                                   }}{12}{figure.caption.24}%
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.5 ...({(}\def ){)}\let \reserved@d =<\def \par }
                                                  }{12}{figure.caption.24}%
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

I have not modified `\cite{}` or anything else. There is no custom code used.

Comment: Please always provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Not only would it help to see what packages could interact with the problem, it'd also make things easier for people willing to help you.

Comment: `{\numberline {4}{\ignorespaces Liste der zehn Themengebiete \protected \ETC.` shows a corrupt `aux` file, use the overleaf menu to delete the cache of generated files

Answer (score 2):

Use `\protect` (or nothing).

`\protected` is e-tex primitive command only used, like `\long`, as a prefix for `\def` and related commands.

Comment: Im stupid. I did not even realize that I used ```\protected``` instead of ```\protect```.  I did not even know that ```\protected``` exists. Thank you very much. It solved the issue!